# Field names not showing up on profile screen Wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress, profile, templates, theme, fields

New to Civi, but not new to CRMs/Wordpress.

When using many of the themes that Wordpress provides (actually this problem occurs with everyone I have tried so far), the field names for a profile signup form do not show up.

[image: With template]

However, if I just use the base theme, they do.

[image: Without template]

Any suggestions on how to address this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a CSS issue.

I would suggest to create a new css file in you custom directory like `/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/my_css/my_stylesheet.css` Navigate to **Administer->System Settings->Resource URLs** and set your **Custom css URL** to the css file `http://yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/my_css/my_stylesheet.css`
more info on how to set a custom CSS path [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Theming+CiviCRM).

In your CSS file put this:

```
.label {
   color: #000 !important;
}
```

The field names/labels are there but they have a white color.

I guess that if put the same style in your Wordpress theme stylesheet section it will override Civi's stylesheet, but the above would be the correct and recommended way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be a .css issue. I approached it a touch differently, and it seems to work with all themes now. I am using the theme-my-login plugin, and I added the above .label code in the main .css file. So far so good, and it means I can play with different themes. Not sure if that interferes with ACL settings between WP and Civi though.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but you don't  need an extra plugin for that, if you have a FTP access or access to the server, I highly  recommend the Custom CSS path. Another tip if you are using a WordPress theme, I would encourage you to create a child theme, that way you have a grained control over styles and customization.